# Where is the location of W3C Web SQL Database in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, web-sql

From PhoneGap site, I know that it supports using Web SQL.
Here, I have few things that are not clear:

1. If I restart the apps, will the database disappear?
2. If no, where is it? Can I go to File Explorer to see and what is the format of it? sqlite?
3. Is Web SQL equal to SQLite??

Please help to give idea^^